# Sentence embeddings BERT

Tags: embedding, sentence, bert-language-model

I need an info.
I used this: https://towardsdatascience.com/improving-sentence-embeddings-with-bert-and-representation-learning-dfba6b444f6b to extract features but I got word embeddings.

If I want sentence embeddings using BERT traines on my data, how can I do?

Example: sentence "I want running" --> result [1,768] array embeddings
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend several aproaches. If you use HuggingFace, try the following [suggestion](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/1950#issuecomment-558679189):

```
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
input_ids = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode("Hello, my dog is cute")).unsqueeze(0)  # 
Batch size 1
outputs = model(input_ids)
last_hidden_states = outputs[0]  # The last hidden-state is the first element of the 
output tuple
```

I invite you to use [Sentence_Transformers](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers). The project fine-tunes BERT / RoBERTa / DistilBERT / ALBERT / XLNet with a siamese or triplet network structure to produce semantically meaningful sentence embeddings. You can employ Flair to test the [Sentence Transformer](https://github.com/flairNLP/flair/blob/master/resources/docs/TUTORIAL_5_DOCUMENT_EMBEDDINGS.md#sentencetransformerdocumentembeddings).

Alternatively you may try Flair TransformerDocumentEmbeddings. See [examples](https://github.com/flairNLP/flair/blob/master/resources/docs/TUTORIAL_5_DOCUMENT_EMBEDDINGS.md#transformerdocumentembeddings).